# Use of the present perfect simple by persons in authority making a report

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, perfect-constructions

I read this report, made by a senior coroner at an inquest, and I wondered whether it has become common for the present perfect simple to be used in this way?

"She had been missing for a few days and it appears she has become disorientated and become entangled with brambles and bushes and hypothermia set in."

Surely "she became disorientated" and "became entangled" would be "better" grammar? It seems that policemen and other persons in authority tend to use this form, especially when making a report.

Comment: has in any case is an outright error. It should be: had become disorientated. **Could just be a typo. I doubt any coroner would make that mistake when speaking**. That would give you: had become disoriented. Also: became entangled would be better.

Comment: It should be the past perfect. At the time the body was found, she _had been_ missing for a few days. Apparently she _had become_ disorientated and _[had] become_ entangled.

Comment: *She **had been** missing for a few days and it **appears...*** is almost certainly an invalid mixing of Past Perfect and Present. Should probably be either ***was** missing* + ***appears*** OR ***had been** missing* + ***appeared***. But even if the initial Past Perfect usage is "correct", it would usually only occur ***once***, after which any further references to "the same point in past time" would normally revert to Simple Past anyway. Repeated use of Perfect forms is usually stylistically clumsy, and best avoided.